# Discovering which VALUE constructor was used in a value

Tags: haskell

Im a OOP/Imperative programmer trying to learn haskell and I am developing a card game as an exercise.

At the time, im trying to define the library deck as it follows:

```
data Suit = Hearts
      | Diamonds
      | Spades
      | Clubs
        deriving(Show, Eq)

type CardValue = Int

data Card = Ace   {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Two   {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Three {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Four  {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Five  {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Six   {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Seven {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Eight {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Nine  {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Ten   {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Jack  {cSuit :: Suit}
          | Queen {cSuit :: Suit}
          | King  {cSuit :: Suit}
            deriving(Show, Eq)

type Hand = [Card]
type Deck = [Card]

cardValue :: Card -> Int
cardValue card =
      | card.ValueConstructorName == Ace   = 11
      | card.ValueConstructorName == Seven = 10
      | otherwise                          = 0
```

1) card.ValueConstructorName is a fantasy field/method/whatever. Is there a way to achieve this using Guards?

2) Do I really need to type '{cSuit :: Suit}' in every alternative of the value constructor?

3) Is this way of abstracting a card deck a reasonable one? I mean, using nested types
thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) This is called pattern matching.

```
cardValue (Ace suit) = 11
cardValue (Seven suit) = 10
cardValue  ....
```

2) No. This would be a quite tedious way to represent cards. There is a very obvious pattern here; in haskell whenever you see a very repetitive pattern, you can guarantee there is some way to abstract something out to make things nicer. Try the following:

```
data Value = Ace | Two | Three | .... | King deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
```

The best part about this is you can derive `Enum` for a data type like this one, and `Enum` defines a function called `fromEnum` which will convert a `CardValue` to an `Int`. As you might expect, the 0th constructor will be 0, etc, so if ace == 1 then:

```
cardValue1 :: Value -> Int
cardValue1 x = 1 + fromEnum x
```

Then you define a card:

```
data Card = Card Value Suit
```

or if you really want records:

```
data Card = Card {valueOfCard :: Value, suitOfCard :: Suit}
```

but usually using records for data types with 2 fields is pretty pointless. Or even:

```
type Card = (Value, Suit)
```

then:

```
cardValue :: Card -> Int
cardValue (Card v _) = cardValue1 v
```

3) 'Almost all' types are nested. You don't really have a choice except nesting types. There are a handful of primitive types which you will almost certainly never even see and every other type is just some combination of these primitives.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is pattern matching:

```
cardValue :: Card -> Int
cardValue (Ace suit) = ...
cardValue (Two suit) = ...
cardValue (Three suit) = ...
...
```

You can this or a case statement

```
cardValue :: Card -> Int
cardValue card = case card of
    Ace suit -> ...
    Two suit -> ...
    ...
```

As for whether this is a good model or not, I would recommend against it.  The way user2407038 has shown is a better alternative, particularly when combined with the `Enum` and `Bounded` typeclasses.